# Move content downwards off screen and fill the space

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to come up with a solution to this design issue, which seems simple but it's perplexing me.

I have content fixed to the bottom of the screen - some of it is always present, some is hidden from time to time.

The crux is that I want the content above to drop down. I have had some success with javascript but its not perfect. The nearest I've got so far is using max-height.

https://jsfiddle.net/6jax19gf/29/

The fiddle is a working representation of what I'm trying to achieve using max-height. However, max height isn't ideal because much of the content is dynamic.

I'd like to come up with a better solution that isn't hard-coded using max-height.

```css
#fixed-footer {
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
}

#fixed-footer-floating {
  padding:0 16px;
  margin-bottom:16px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.fab-button {
  background-color:lime;
  display:inline-block;
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
  border-radius:50%;
}

#fixed-footer-auto {
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  max-height: 76px;
  
}

.some-content {
  padding:14px 16px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

#fixed-footer:hover #fixed-footer-auto {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in, max-height 0.4s 0.2s ease-out;
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed-footer">
<div id="fixed-footer-floating">
  <a class="fab-button"></a> This content always floats above the red box!
</div>
<div id="fixed-footer-auto">
    <div class="some-content">This area is responsive so may expand or contract vertically depending on the screen size and page state. It's content can be made to made disappear completely on certain events.</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hover over the bottom red area to make the content disappear. This would usually be triggered using javascript.

Comment: So where is the fiddle and where is the JS you are using?

Comment: what do you want to achieve...?...Its not clear in your question...

Comment: @Bhuwan - I want to achieve a similar design to what I have here, except the I don't want to use max-height for the transition.

Comment: @NoobishPro - The fiddle has been added. I've ditched the javascript that I've been using fir now as it wasn't playing very well with the rest. Not all transitions were completing.

Comment: But we need to know, when do you want to hide it, when do you want to expand it? Expand on hover? Hide on scroll? What exactly? And why should the content move with it? That sounds a bit odd. Or do other fixed elements have to move with it?

Comment: @NoobishPro. The  green button always floats on top but the content can be anything. However this is not important - it's simply a container that must be responsive and can disappear. Everything else sits above this fixed footer at the bottom of the page. I've used hover for demonstration purposes only - the live function will use javascript to add classes. The content will be displayed when the window is at the top scroll position but will be hidden when the user scrolls down the page. Detecting scroll is not an issue it's making a responsive disappearing box at the foot of the page.

Comment: @NoobishPro - the crux is that translate/scale leaves a space where the content was. This means that the content above (just the other stuff in the fixed footer) never slides to the bottom. In the example I've used a combination of translate and max-height to achieve the outcome but max-height requires a number of px to be hard-coded. In addition to being responsive, the content will also be subject to change, so a hard-coded height isn't ideal.

Comment: @JohnOhara still don't know what you want to achieve for sure, though. Maybe I'm just stupid though. You want the thing to grow vertically, but contract. You're speaking of a max-height, so you want it to limit itself on how high it can get? I don't see the use of translate here. Can't you just make the wrapper `overflow:hidden;` and give said wrapper a static height on-scroll? Give the elements inside the fixed element a top 0 and they'll automatically go down/up with the wrapper's contractions/expands? `overflow:hidden` would in turn make sure you don't get "overscroll" from it.

Comment: @JohnOhara something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6jax19gf/52/ ?

Comment: @NoobishPro - There is a fixed footer with content. All content inside the fixed footer is responsive so I can't give it a height using CSS. TranslateY doesn't allow the parent to collapse and leaves a space at the bottom. Position takes div's out of the flow so will affect placement. I'm unsure what you mean by your example - maybe a html/css fiddle would help explain.

Comment: Just seen your fiddle - I'll set up a test and let you know how i go on. Thanks

Comment: And? How did you get along?